# SwiftUI: calling objectWillChange.send() not updating child view

Tags: swift, swiftui, publisher, property-wrapper

I have a rather complicated set of views nested in views. When I trigger a button action, I pass along an optional block through my `viewModel` class which calls `objectWillChange.send()` on that `viewModel` and I know that it's being triggered because the other parts of my view are updating. One of the child views (which is observing that `viewModel` changes) doesn't update until I click on part of it (which changes `viewModel.selectedIndex` and triggers redraw so I know it's listening for published changes).

**Why isn't the update triggering the child view (in this case `PurchaseItemGrid`) to redraw itself?**

Here's where I setup the call to update...

```
struct RightSideView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TrenchesPurchases
            
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
            PurchaseItemGrid(viewModel: viewModel)      // <-- View not updating
            Button {
                viewModel.purchaseAction() {
                    viewModel.objectWillChange.send()   // <-- Triggers redraw, reaches breakpoint here
                }
            } label: {
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here's where the optional is called (and I've not only visually confirmed this is happening as other parts of the view redraw, it also hits breakpoint here)...

```
class TrenchesPurchases: ObservableObject, CanPushCurrency {

    // MARK: - Properties

    @Published private var model = Purchases()

    // MARK: - Properties: Computed

    var selectedIndex: Int {
        get { return model.selectedIndex }
        set { model.selectedIndex = newValue }
    }

    var purchaseAction: BlockWithBlock {
        { complete in                    
            ...
            
            complete?()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And here's the view that's not updating as expected...

```
struct PurchaseItemGrid: View {

   @ObservedObject var viewModel: TrenchesPurchases
    
   var body: some View {
        VStack {
            itemRow(indices:  0...3)
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func itemRow(indices range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.purchaseItems[range], id: \.id) { item in
                PurchaseItemView(item: item,
                                 borderColor: viewModel.selectedIndex == item.id ? .green : Color(Colors.oliveGreen))
                .onTapGesture { viewModel.selectedIndex = item.id }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code workingdog asked for...

```
struct Purchases {

    // MARK: - Properties

    var selectedIndex = 15

    let items: [PurchaseItem] = buildCollectionOfItems()

    // MARK: - Functions

    // MARK: - Functions: Static

    // TODO: Define Comments
    static func buildCollectionOfItems() -> [PurchaseItem] {
        return row0() + row1() + row2() + row3()
}

static func row0() -> [PurchaseItem] {
    var items = [PurchaseItem]()
    
    let grenade = Ammo(ammo: .grenade)
    items.append(grenade)
    
        let bullets = Ammo(ammo: .bullets)
        items.append(bullets)
    
        let infiniteBullets = Unlock(mode: .defense)
        items.append(infiniteBullets)
    
        let unlimitedInfantry = Unlock(mode: .offense)
        items.append(unlimitedInfantry)
    
        return items
    }

    static func row1() -> [PurchaseItem] {
        var items = [PurchaseItem]()
    
        for unit in UnitType.allCases {
            let item = Unit(unit: unit)
            items.append(item)
        }
        
        return items
    }

    static func row2() -> [PurchaseItem] {
        var items = [PurchaseItem]()

        let brits = NationItem(nation: .brits)
        items.append(brits)
    
        let turks = NationItem(nation: .turks)
        items.append(turks)
    
        let usa = NationItem(nation: .usa)
        items.append(usa)
    
        let insane = DifficultyItem(difficulty: .insane)
        items.append(insane)
    
        return items
    }

    static func row3() -> [PurchaseItem] {
        var items = [PurchaseItem]()

        let offenseLootBox = Random(mode: .offense)
        items.append(offenseLootBox)
    
        let defenseLootBox = Random(mode: .defense)
        items.append(defenseLootBox)
    
        let currency = Currency(isCheckin: false)
        items.append(currency)
    
        let checkIn = Currency(isCheckin: true)
        items.append(checkIn)
    
        return items
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using just `viewModel.model.selectedIndex = item.id` instead of your `var selectedIndex: Int {get..set..}` thing.
Can you show what `Purchases` is? For example, a struct or a `nested` ObservedObject?

Comment: That part is working fine, its the purchase action block that's not triggering. Purchases is a separate struct (not nested).

Comment: if as you say, the problem is to do with the `purchaseAction`, at least show us the code for it, and the struct `Purchases`, so we can evaluate what is going on.

Comment: I've added the `Purchases` code, although not sure what that has to do with the viewModel sending the publish notification. Maybe that's my issue. The code for the `purchaseAction` has been there the whole time, marked with comments that say "Triggers redraw, reaches breakpoint here."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was that the `PurchaseItemGrid` was noticing the observed item being published, but the change I was trying to trigger was in the `PurchaseItemView` which did not have an observed object.

I assumed that when the `PurchaseItemGrid` observed the change and was redrawn, the `itemRow` method would redraw a new collection of `PurchaseItemView`'s that would then have their image updated to match the new state.

This was further compounded because the `onTapGesture` was triggering a redraw of the `PurchaseItemView`, and to be honest I'm still not sure how the `PurchaseItemGrid` could redraw itself while still using the same `PurchaseItemView`'s in it's body; but it may have to do with how @ViewBuilder works and because the views were created in an entirely separate method.

So, long story short: **make sure each view you want to update has some form of observer, don't rely on the parent's redraw to create new child views.**

Comment: You need to convert itemRow from a func to a View with its own body. Also ForEach is a View not a for loop it doesn't work with indicies it needs the actual data to work correctly.